# Going to the end of a substring in c#

Tags: c#, string, substring

The comment // go to end, I can't figure out how to cleanly end the substring :(
Is there a simpler way to go to the end of the substring rather than mathing out the number by myself? For more complex strings this would be too hard

```
        string word = Console.ReadLine();
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(file);
        using (var far = File.CreateText(resultfile))
        {
            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                StringBuilder NewL = new StringBuilder();
                int ind = line.IndexOf(word);
                if (ind >= 0)
                {
                    if (ind == 0)
                    {
                        NewL.Append(line.Substring(ind+ word.Length +1, // go to end);
                    }else{
                    NewL.Append(line.Substring(0, ind - 1));
                    NewL.Append(line.Substring(ind + word.Length + 1, // go to end));}
                    far.WriteLine(NewL);
                }
                else
                {
                    far.WriteLine(line);
                }

            }
```

I don't know what more details the stackoverflow wants, anyone who can answer this pretty sure can clearly understand this simple code anyways.

Comment: Are you just trying to remove a certain word from the input lines loaded from a file and then rewrite the lines?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`String.Substring(int)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_Substring_System_Int32_) overload, which automatically continues to the end of the source string:

```
NewL.Append(line.Substring(ind + word.Length + 1));
```

> Retrieves a substring from this instance. The substring starts at a specified character position and continues to the end of the string.

Comment: I tried this before , but didn't notice that I forgot a " ) " at the end ... Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that you are just trying to remove a certain word from the loaded lines. If this is your task then you can simply replace the word with an empty string

```
foreach (string line in lines)
{
    string newLine = line.Replace(word, "");
    far.WriteLine(newLine);
}
```

Or even without an explicit loop with a bit of Linq

```
var result = lines.Select(x = x.Replace(word,""));
File.WriteAllLines("yourFile.txt", result);
```

Or, given the requirement to match an additional character after the word you can solve it with Regex.

```
Regex r = new Regex(word + ".");
var result = lines.Select(x => r.Replace(x, ""));
File.WriteAllLines("yourFile.txt", result);
```

Comment: Have to replace word + 1 character after it with nothing

Comment: I see, then perhaps Regex could help.

Comment: Yeah I already finished this with Regex, but trying to see if it's possible for me to do without it. Thanks